# Using strSQL to order by Multiple Columns in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a simple strSQL string in Access VBA:

```
Sub SampleReadCurve()

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim CurveID As Long
    Dim MarkRunID As Long



CurveID = 15

   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & CurveID & _
         " ORDER BY MaturityDate"


Debug.Print strSQL

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)

Dim MarkAsofDate as Date
```

Now I have two problems. I used a Make Table query to generate the table `VolatilityOutput`. One of the fields is called `MarkAsofDate`. I set the query to select the max value for this field. The relevant field in the table is thus "`MaxOfMarkasOfDate`", taking the maximum value in this column.

I want to order by this `MaxOfMarkasofDate` column in addition to the `MaturityDate` column. So I need to change my strSQL string to order by `MaturityDate` AND `MaxOfMarkasofDate`. What is the correct syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: Is `MaxOfMarkasOfDate` a column in `VolatilityOuput` ?

Comment: however if possible I'd like it to select the max value specifically in the strSQL string, rather than in a Make Table Query as I've done already

Comment: Then you just need to list them in order which you want the data to be sorted. `ORDER BY MaxofMarkasOfDate, MaturityDate`. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ORDER-BY-Clause-E8EA47F7-5388-460A-BEC8-DCC81792D762 . If you select max value from entire input, what is the reason to sort based on that value? It wouldn't change the order.